# How can I transmit the force induced by magnetic torque?

Tags: torque, electromagnetism, magnets, transmission, forces

So I'm working on a project where I'm trying to transmit the force induced by magnetic torque onto people's hands, thereby making it a haptic feedback system. This is the stucture that I designed to experiment with.

[image]

The permanent magnet could freely rotate around the axis of rotation (there're bearings on both ends of the axis). The platform is connected to the force/torque sensor via adhesives. The principle of this structure is shown in the figure below.

[image]

When there's external magnetic field **B**, the permanent magnet could only rotate around the axis over a tiny angle before it hit an obstacle, creating a pressuring force **F**, which is the force that I want to transmit to people's hands that are holding the platform (in this case it's the sensor).

However, my analysis is flawed. I didn't do a full force analysis and I didn't take the pressure between the axis and the bearing into account. In reality, the force should be like this.

[image]

Where **FN** is the force I omitted. The force FN would go to the bearing, and then to the platform, and then the force sensor. And because FN (or to be more precise, the difference between FN before the external magnetic field and after the external magnetic field) and F are in opposite direction with the same magnitude, they cancel each other out. Therefore, nothing could be detected by the force sensor.
So my question is: how can I transform the magnetic torque into force that could be transmitted? Any idea would be welcomed and appreciated, but it would be better if it fits this project's background (force feedback on human's hands)